# Rel attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rel

I want to create dynamic html which needs to render as code given below:

```
<a rel="{gallery: 'gal', smallimage: 'a',largeimage: 'b'}" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="x1.jpg"></a>
```

What I wrote following code in jQuery to achive above:

```
for(i=1; i<=4; i++){
    var rela="{gallery:'gal', smallimage:'a', largeimage: 'b'}";
    html += "<a href='javascript:void(0);' rel='"+rela+"' ><img src='x"+i+".jpg' /></a>";
}
```

But when it's executed it renders as below:

```
<a 'b'}'="" largeimage:="" smallimage:'a',="" gal',="" rel="{gallery:" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="x1" class="img1"></a>
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that you're using single quotes to denote attribute values which is the immediate problem, the main problem is that you're putting pseudo-JSON in a `rel` attribute, which is... wrong. What exactly do you want to accomplish with this?

Comment: I am trying to use jQZoom plugin and trying to follow the pattern  given in jqzoom example file ... please use this url to view what exactly I want to do with above code http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using attributes to store data on objects isn't exactly a smart idea as you found out yourself, it doesn't work as you might want it to work. Especially json.

In your case you're trying to store json? Or an object with qoutes in it in the html, the browser however will treat the first qoute it encounters as a closure of the rel attribute.. messing stuff up bigtime.

Store the different properties in a seperate data attribute, or considder storing the items in a js variable and the anchor an id. When you need the data again you use the id on the anchor to recapture the data from the js variable. ([read more here on data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)).

Comment: I am trying to use jQZoom plugin and trying to follow the patter given in jqzoom example file

Comment: As I understand you want to dynamically insert some images and initiate jqzoom on it?

Comment: Ok quickly reading through http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/ I can confirm that the problem you are experiencing is simply mixing double and single qoutes. Use double qoutes for html attributes and single qoutes inside your json string to keep it all in one attribute. As a side note, that plugin is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

```
html += "<a href='javascript:void(0);' rel=\""+rela+"\" ><img src='x"+i+".jpg' /></a>";
```

or

```
var rela='{gallery:"gal", smallimage:"a", largeimage: "b"}';
```

Comment: You just used double qoutes... yes this might work but is still bad advice if you ask me.